# making custom popover bottom position fixed and let it stretch towards top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making custom popover similar to a bootstrap popover, I able to make popovers in all the directions but in the top direction I am facing challenges as i want my popover to fixed is bottom just above the popover opening button and when its content increases its height increase towards top while keeping bottom fixed.

```js
let popoverBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle='popover']");
let popover = document.querySelector(".popover-overlay");
let popoverHeading = document.querySelector(".popover-overlay-heading h4");
let popoverContent = document.querySelector(".popover-overlay-content p");
for (let i = 0; i < popoverBtn.length; i++) {
  if (popoverBtn[i]) {
    popoverBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      let top = e.target.offsetTop;
      let left = e.target.offsetLeft;
      let width = e.target.offsetWidth;
      let height = e.target.offsetHeight;
      let heading = e.target.getAttribute("title");
      let description = e.target.getAttribute("data-content");
      let popoverHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(popover).height);
      let popoverWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(popover).width);
      let dir = e.target.getAttribute("data-placement");
      popoverHeading.textContent = heading;
      popoverContent.textContent = description;
      popover.classList.add("active");
      popover.style.top = '0px';
      popover.style.left = '0px'

      switch (dir) {
        case "top":
          popover.style.top = top - popoverHeight - 20 + "px";
          popover.style.left = left + "px";
          popover.style.bottom = top;
          break;
        case "bottom":
          popover.style.top = top + height + 5 + "px";
          popover.style.left = left + "px";
          break;
        case "left":
          popover.style.top = top + "px";
          popover.style.left = left - popoverWidth - 20 + "px";
          break;
        case "right":
          popover.style.top = top + "px";
          popover.style.left = left + width + 30 + "px";
          break;
        default:
          popover.style.top = top + "px";
          popover.style.left = left + width + 30 + "px";
          break;
      }



    })
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3,
h4,
p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.bg-light-gray {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

section {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

section button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.popover-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: none;
  width: 280px;
  height: 121px;
}

.popover-overlay.active {
  display: block;
}

.popover-overlay-heading {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.popover-overlay-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="popover-overlay">
  <div class="popover-overlay-heading">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="popover-overlay-content">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <section class="bg-gray">
    <button data-placement="top" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging.">Popover Top</button>
    <button data-placement="left" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Popover Left</button>
    <button data-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Popover Right</button>
    <button data-placement="bottom" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Popover Bottom</button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove `popover.style.top = top - popoverHeight - 20 + "px";` from your switch case for "top" it will place the bottom of your popover at the top of the button, hence your code...  `popover.style.bottom = top;`. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top popover element height must to be redefined

```js
let popoverBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle='popover']");
      let popover = document.querySelector(".popover-overlay");
      let popoverHeading = document.querySelector(".popover-overlay-heading h4");
      let popoverContent = document.querySelector(".popover-overlay-content p");
      for (let i = 0; i < popoverBtn.length; i++) {
        if (popoverBtn[i]) {
          popoverBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            let top = e.target.offsetTop;
            let left = e.target.offsetLeft;
            let width = e.target.offsetWidth;
            let height = e.target.offsetHeight;
            let heading = e.target.getAttribute("title");
            let description = e.target.getAttribute("data-content");
            let popoverHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(popover).height);
            let popoverWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(popover).width);
            let dir = e.target.getAttribute("data-placement");
            popoverHeading.textContent = heading;
            popoverContent.textContent = description;
            popover.classList.add("active");
            popover.style.top = "0px";
            popover.style.left = "0px";

            switch (dir) {
              case "top":
                popover.style.height = popoverHeight + "px";
                popoverHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(popover).height);
                popover.style.top = top - popoverHeight - 1 + "px";
                popover.style.left = left + "px";
                popover.style.bottom = top;
                break;
              case "bottom":
                popover.style.top = top + height + 5 + "px";
                popover.style.left = left + "px";
                break;
              case "left":
                popover.style.top = top + "px";
                popover.style.left = left - popoverWidth - 20 + "px";
                break;
              case "right":
                popover.style.top = top + "px";
                popover.style.left = left + width + 30 + "px";
                break;
              default:
                popover.style.top = top + "px";
                popover.style.left = left + width + 30 + "px";
                break;
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

```css
 body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      h3,
      h4,
      p {
        margin: 0px;
      }

      .container {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .bg-gray {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      .bg-light-gray {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      section {
        min-height: 400px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 20px;
      }

      section button {
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        background-color: #dc3545;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
      }

      .popover-overlay {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        display: none;
        width: 280px;
        /* height: 121px; */
        height: fit-content;
      }

      .popover-overlay.active {
        display: block;
      }

      .popover-overlay-heading {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .popover-overlay-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 1rem;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="popover-overlay">
      <div class="popover-overlay-heading">
        <h4></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="popover-overlay-content">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <section class="bg-gray">
        <button data-placement="top" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title"
         data-content="It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging.">
          Popover Top
        </button>
        <button
          data-placement="left"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
          data-toggle="popover"
          title="Popover title"
          data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"
        >
          Popover Left
        </button>
        <button
          data-placement="right"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
          data-toggle="popover"
          title="Popover title"
          data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"
        >
          Popover Right
        </button>
        <button
          data-placement="bottom"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
          data-toggle="popover"
          title="Popover title"
          data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"
        >
          Popover Bottom
        </button>
      </section>
    </div>
```